# Distribution of $(X,XY)$ with $X$ a standard Gaussian and $Y$ a Rademacher random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a standard gaussian rv and $Y$ a Rademacher rv such that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
It is easy to show that $Z=XY$ has has standard gaussian distribution.
Find the distribution of $(X,Z)$ and deduce the distribution of $Z$ given $X$.

The obvious approach here seems to be to calculate $\mathbb P(X\le x,Z\le z)$ for $(x,z)\in\mathbb R^2$ but since $X$ and $Z$ aren't independent I don't really see how to proceed.

As for the second part of the question, if we have the distribution $F_{X,Z}$ then it is quite easy to get that of $F_{X|Z}$, but I don't know what $F_{X,Z}$ is.

Comment: How about working out: $$P(X\leq x,XY\leq z)=P(X\leq x,XY\leq z|Y=1)P(Y=1)+P(X\leq x, XY\leq z|Y=-1)P(Y=-1)$$And did you forget mentioning of independence for $X$ and $Y$ maybe?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, I've just added it.

Comment: After trying to apply this method, I find that $P(X\le x,XY\le z)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\min(x,y)}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt+1_{[-z,+\infty[}(x)\int_{-z}^xe^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt\right)$ but this just seems absurdly wrong...

Comment: I would have thought $F_{Z \mid X=x}(z)$ was easier than $F_{X,Z}(x,z)$  and might be done first.  I would also use $F_{X}(x)= \Phi(x)$ as shorthand, and consider the cases $x\ge 0$ and $z<-x, -x \le z \lt x, x\le z$ and the cases $x\lt 0$ and $z<x, x \le z \lt -x, -x\le z$ separately